# Is $f_n=\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Is the sequence of functions uniformly convergent if we know that the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ exist for all $x$ in the domain of interest.

$$f_n=\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

If so, how does one prove this?

Comment: What is the domain? What do we know about $f$? Certainly it will not be uniformly convergent for any given $f$; it may not converge at all.

Comment: This looks like the definition of the derivative - of course, its convergence depends upon the value of $f$.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ continuous?  Is it differentiable?

Comment: Sorry, I was being sloppy. You can assume the derivative of f exists. @S.Ong you are correct, this is the definition of a derivative. I'm struggling to prove that this limit is however uniformly convergent for any given differentiable function

Answer (score 2):

The answer is No in general

Hint: think about a differentiable function which is not continuously differentiable

Comment: Under what conditions would $f_n$ converge uniformly?

Comment: @LukeTaylor I suggest you post this as a question and linked it above question... because what you asked is not that easy to answer as a comment

Comment: Thanks, will do